# Creating rules that aren't repetitive in CLIPS - Expert System

Tags: rules, clips, expert-system

i am VERY new to CLIPS and trying to create an expert system for medical diagnosis. Of course it is just for practice. My code runs so far, however, there are a few things I couldn't get to work.

For the first 3 symptoms (fever, cough, fatigue) if any 2 are answered yes it outputs a diagnosis. If not, it continues on to ask the patient about the less common symptoms. Right now I have made it so that if even one of the uncommon symptomps are answered yes, there is a diagnosis. However, I want to make it so that if atleast 3 of them are answered yes it outputs a diagnosis. The problem is that i dont know how to make a rule that checks for this, without having to make a bunch of separate rules checking for each and every possibility of yes and no combinations which would be tedious.

Here is a link to my code as it is rather long to put on here. https://codeshare.io/arBpq6

Answer (score 1):

Define some deftemplates so you can represent your questions and answers as facts.

```
(deftemplate question
   (slot tier (default 1))
   (slot answer)
   (slot query))

(deftemplate answer
   (slot name)
   (slot tier)
   (slot response))
```

Your system has three tiers of questions which can now be represented as facts:

```
(deffacts questions
   (question (tier 1)
             (answer patient-contact)
             (query "Has the patient been within 6 feet for a total of 15 minutes or more with someone who has confirmed COVID-19? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 2)
             (answer patient-fever)
             (query "Has the patient been having mild to high fever recently? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 2)
             (answer patient-dry-cough)
             (query "Has the patient been experiencing a dry cough? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 2)
             (answer patient-fatigue)
             (query "Has the patient been experiencing unusual levels of fatigue? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3) 
             (answer patient-senses)
             (query "Has the patient been experiencing a loss of taste or smell? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-nasal)
             (query "Has the patient been experiencing nasal congestion? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-conjunctivitis)
             (query "Does the patient have conjunctivitis (red eyes)? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-sorethroat)
             (query "Does the patient have a sore throat? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-headache)
             (query "Has the patient been having frequent headaches? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-pain)
             (query "Has the patient been experiencing joint and muscle pains? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-rashes)
             (query "Does the patient have any kind of skin rashes? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-nausea)
             (query "Has the patient been experiencing nausea or been vomiting? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-diarrhea)
             (query "Has the patient been having diarrhea? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-dizziness)
             (query "Has the patient been experiencing dizziness or chills? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-breath)
             (query "Has the patient been experiencing shortness of breath? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-appetite)
             (query "Has the patient been experiencing a loss of appetite? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-confusion)
             (query "Has the patient been experiencing unusual levels of confusion? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-pressure)
             (query "Does the patient have persistent pain or pressure in their chest? (yes/no) "))
   (question (tier 3)
             (answer patient-temperature)
             (query "Does the patient have a high temperature (above 38 degrees Celsius)? (yes/no) ")))
```

A generic rule can now be created for asking questions. Questions are removed once answered and questions will not be asked until all questions from higher tiers have been answered.

```
(defrule ask-question
   (not (covid ?))
   ?f <- (question (tier ?t)
                   (answer ?a)
                   (query ?q))
   (not (question (tier ?t2&:(< ?t2 ?t))))
   =>
   (retract ?f)
   (assert (answer (name ?a)
                   (tier ?t)
                   (response (patient-answer-p ?q)))))
```

You can now add rules for each tier that look for a specific number of answers:

```
(defrule immediate-test ""
   (declare (salience 10))
   (not (covid ?))
   (exists (answer (tier 1)
                   (response yes)))
   =>
   (assert (covid "The patient should be tested immediately as it is highly likely the virus could be transferred to them.")))
      
(defrule two-common-symptoms ""
   (declare (salience 10))
   (not (covid ?))
   (exists (answer (tier 2)
                   (name ?n1)
                   (response yes))
           (answer (tier 2)
                   (name ?n2&~?n1)
                   (response yes))
           (answer (tier 2)
                   (name ?n3&~?n2&~?n1)
                   (response no)))
   =>
   (assert (covid "The patient shows 2 of the common symptoms, and it is recommended that they get tested.")))

(defrule all-common-symptoms ""
   (declare (salience 10))
   (not (covid ?))
   (exists (answer (tier 2)
                   (name ?n1)
                   (response yes))
           (answer (tier 2)
                   (name ?n2&~?n1)
                   (response yes))
           (answer (tier 2)
                   (name ?n3&~?n2&~?n1)
                   (response yes)))
   =>
   (assert (covid "The patient shows all 3 of the common symptoms, and it is highly recommended that they get tested.")))

(defrule three-uncommon-symptoms ""
   (declare (salience 10))
   (not (covid ?))
   (exists (answer (tier 3)
                   (name ?n1)
                   (response yes))
           (answer (tier 3)
                   (name ?n2&~?n1)
                   (response yes))
           (answer (tier 3)
                   (name ?n3&~?n2&~?n1)
                   (response yes)))
   =>
   (assert (covid "The patient is showing at least 3 of the uncommon symptoms, and therefore it is recommended that they be tested.")))
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the amount of detail you have provided me. This makes a lot of sense and is easy to follow.